# How do i combine Selector with my Utility function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

While writing tests with [TestCafe](https://testcafe.devexpress.com/) i'm creating **utility functions**, but there seems to be a problem when using the **Selector('')** method inside any function.

The Selector('') method works fine inside test files and also when importing from another file (utility_selectors.js). I think I need to include something inside the function, but I'm stuck and can't seem to find the solution.

My goal is to create a function to select mouse click coordinates.

---

**Utility_selectors.js**

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

export const viewport = Selector('.viewport').find('canvas');
```

**Utility_functions.js**

```
import * as s from './selectors.js';

export const selectPoint = (x,y) => {
  return s.viewport + ",{ offsetX :" + x + ", offsetY :" + y + "}"
}
```

OR (both don't work)

```
export function selectPoint(x,y){
  return s.viewport + ",{ offsetX :" + x + ", offsetY :" + y + "}"
}
```

**Testfile.js** (utility function in action)

```
import { selectPoint } from '../utilities/functions.js';

test('example utility function', async (t) => {
  await t.click(selectPoint(100,200));
});
```

**When executing, the following error occurs in cmd:**

```
  SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'function
  __$$clientFunction$$() {
  const testRun = builder._getTestRun();
  const callsite = (0, _getCallsite.getCallsiteForMethod)(builder.callsiteNames.execution);
  const args = [];

  // OPTIMIZATION: don't leak `arguments` object.
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) args.push(arguments[i]);

  return builder._executeCommand(args, testRun, callsite);
  },{ offsetX :100, offsetY :200}' is not a valid selector.
```

---

So long story short, I want to include the TestCafe's Selector('') method inside a utility function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't you just need `t.click(s.viewport, {offsetX: 100, offsetY: 200})`?

Comment: That is true, the original code is relatively short, but for this particular project i need a lot of coordinates and that makes it a bit shorter and easier to use. I'm also interested to know if there is a solution to this problem for future functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your provided code will not work since you are trying to concatenate a string to a generated function. This string should be an Object passed as the second argument to the click function.

If you always use the same selector, I can imagine you would want to create a utility like `clickPoint(t, 100,200)`.

This can be achieved by the following utility function.

```
import * as s from './selectors.js';

export const clickPoint = (t, x, y) => {
  return t.click(s.viewport, { offsetX : x, offsetY: y });
};
```

Your testfile would look like this:

```
import { clickPoint } from '../utilities/functions.js';

test('example utility function', async (t) => {
  await clickPoint(t, 100, 200);
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If anyone else want to use my code, I have made it a bit cleaner.

utility_functions_js

```
import { t } from 'testcafe';

export const clickPoint = (x, y) => {
  return t.doubleClick(s.viewport, { offsetX : x, offsetY: y });
};
```

Now you can write:

```
await clickPoint(x,y)
```

instead of

```
await clickPoint(t,x,y)
```

Cheers :)